# Why this question closed as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question, dupehammer

I am pointing at this question: [Why does Math.cbrt(1728) produce a more accurate result than Math.pow(1728, 1/3)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26951407), even gold badge closed it as such; the question didn't ask why `Math.pow` isn't accurate, but why method such as `Math.cbrt` that meant to do the same functionality as `Math.pow(x,1/3)`, resulting in different outputs.

My guess is that none of those that voted to close the question read it carefully enough, unless there is another valid reason; enlighten me if there's any of them.

Comment: Is the answer different then?

Comment: @rene The answer can reference to the source code and show us how `Math.cbrt` implemented different than expected and explain why it outputs different result in this particular situation. TL;DR: Yes.

Comment: Your question is now reopened.

Answer (score 3):

For me personally you are correct:

> My guess is that none of those that voted to close the question read it carefully enough

I didn't take enough time to fully understand if the subtilties of rounding errors where indeed the root cause of the issue of the OP.

If other members wouldn't be so kind to cast a re-open vote I would have done so myself.

Next time I'll read and try to understand both the question and the duplicate better before I cast a close vote. I stand corrected.